# find a specific child element in html with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The example im stuck with is like this

```
<div class="nav-links">
<div class="nav-previous">
    <a href="prevlink" rel="prev">
        <span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">Previous </span> 
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Previous post:</span> <br>
        <span class="post-title">
            Title
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="nav-next">
    <a href="nextlink" rel="next">
        <span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">Next </span> <span class="screen-reader-text">Next post:</span>
         <br>
         <span class="post-title">
            Title
         </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

my ultimate goal is to get the value of href but all i could is bet the whole <div class ...  element. im using beautifulsoup python

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Comment: What href do you need? The `prevlink` or `nextlink` ?

Comment: thanks i got an answer i should have just typed soup.find("div", {"class": "nav-next"}).find("a").attrs['href'] and  soup.find("div", {"class": "nav-previous"}).find("a").attrs['href']

Answer (score 1):

You can print all the values for href by finding all the links in the page

```
links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
    print(link.attrs['href'])
```